# Find maximum of lower values, except 0

Tags: arrays, if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

For a given set of data in a column A (A1:A12):

```
10
0
20
11
2
7
0
0
5
6
3
```

I would like to find out a formula, that would find maximum number, from the lowest 3, excluding zeros.

In such case, the lowest numbers (excluding zeros) are 2,3,5, so the result would be 5.

If not the zeros, I would use SMALL(A1:A12, 3), but it will not remove zeros from equation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(SMALL(IF(A1:A12=0,, A1:A12), 3))
```

[image]